# Modify message's header on consuming middleware

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

Is there any way to modify message's headers in the middleware during message consuming?
As I can see Headers interface on ConsumeContext does not provide any way to set header, is there some another way to achieve that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add headers during consumption with middleware, however, you can add *payloads* to the context which can be used elsewhere in the pipeline.

For instance, if you had an `AuthorizationContext` context, you could add it to the payload within a middleware component:

```
public Task Send(ConsumeContext context, IPipe<ConsumeContext> next)
{
    context.GetOrAddPayload(() => CreateAuthorizationContext());

    return next.Send(context);
}
```

Then, another component or user of the context could access it:

```
public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyMessage> context)
{
    var authorizationContext = context.GetPayload<AuthorizationContext>();

    if(authorizationContext.IsAdmin)
        return UpdateSomething(context);

    throw new NotAuthorizationException("Booo!");
}
```